# Best method for ordering information in a form

Tags: forms, layout, information-architecture, content

Is there a good method for deciding on layout and order of information in a complex form ?
For example - deciding how to order many customer details in a CRM system.

Should the main criteria for order of layout be by importance? By frequency of use? Or by order of use?
I know they are all important but is there a proven method to organize the form?

Comment: **Web Form Design** *by Luke Wroblewski* has all the answers :) [![Web Form Design by Luke Wroblewski](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5F8O.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5F8O.png)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're providing the answer yourself – if the information is both important and frequently used, it should be placed at the forefront of the form. This would make it more practical for those who will be operating or consulting it.

There are various components that can assist in organizing the information effectively. Tabs or accordions can be utilized after the primary data to categorize the remaining details, such as birth information, address, and contact information.

Before you delve further into your design process, I strongly recommend reaching out to the individuals who will be using this tool. Understanding their workflow and how they interact with the information will provide valuable insights for the appropriate design. Remember that, as a UX professional, your primary responsibility is to comprehend the user's needs before taking on the wireframes.

Lastly, despite having proven methods, your user should always have the final say. You could conduct a benchmark analysis on the organization of other CRM tools (hopefully you've already done this) to see the order they use. However, it's equally crucial to examine how your users are using these tools and what their primary pain points are. Considering the effort involved, it might be more worthwhile to engage with your own users for feedback and insights.

Answer (score 0):

With my experiance in designing complex PLM systems and enterprise applications, I came across the below points for best-form designs -

1. Group Relevant information and name the border group for better identity eg:  Basic Details, Order Preferences, Order Details, etc
2. Use Tabber or Accordion to create sections so the user can focus on one step at a time.
3. Provide Table view and card view both for better user experience with data sorting options.